# ogr2ogr: Retrieve multiple layers from WFS in one go

Tags: gdal, wfs, ogr2ogr

I can retrieve a layer of a WFS as, let's say, .gpkg via calling:

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg svo_zonen.gpkg WFS:"http://maps.zh.ch/wfs/FnsNSWFS" svo_zonen
```

What is the syntax to retrieve multiple layers from the same WFS in one go?

I failed to find something relevant online and attempts such as `ogr2ogr ... svo_zonen, heuschreckeninv_90_98` or `ogr2ogr ... svo_zonen heuschreckeninv_90_98` were unsuccessful.

Comment: `ogr2ogr -f gpkg svo_zonen.gpkg WFS:"http://maps.zh.ch/wfs/FnsNSWFS"` without layer name(s) should read the whole datasource. But there may be some server side restrictions.

Comment: True that. Sorry, I was maybe too vague: I actually want to retrieve two specific layers at once rather than the whole datasource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give ogr2ogr a list of the feature types. Names must be given exactly as the service has them in GetCapabilities. You can check the names with ogrinfo like here against a GeoServer demo service that gets installed by default.

```
ogrinfo WFS:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs"
INFO: Open of `WFS:http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs'
      using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=This is the reference implementation of WFS 1.0.0 and WFS 1.1.0, supports all WFS operations including Transaction.
  PROVIDER_NAME=OSGeo
  TITLE=GeoServer Web Feature Service
1: ne:boundary_lines (title: Boundary Lines) (Multi Curve)
2: ne:coastlines (title: Coastlines) (Multi Curve)
3: ne:countries (title: Countries) (Multi Surface)
4: tiger:poly_landmarks (title: Manhattan (NY) landmarks) (Multi Surface)
5: tiger:poi (title: Manhattan (NY) points of interest) (Point)
6: tiger:tiger_roads (title: Manhattan (NY) roads) (Multi Curve)
7: ne:populated_places (title: Populated Places) (Point)
8: sf:archsites (title: Spearfish archeological sites) (Point)
9: sf:bugsites (title: Spearfish bug locations) (Point)
10: sf:restricted (title: Spearfish restricted areas) (Multi Surface)
11: sf:roads (title: Spearfish roads) (Multi Curve)
12: sf:streams (title: Spearfish streams) (Multi Curve)
13: topp:tasmania_cities (title: Tasmania cities) (Multi Point)
14: topp:tasmania_roads (title: Tasmania roads) (Multi Curve)
15: topp:tasmania_state_boundaries (title: Tasmania state boundaries) (Multi Surface)
16: topp:tasmania_water_bodies (title: Tasmania water bodies) (Multi Surface)
17: topp:states (title: USA Population) (Multi Surface)
18: tiger:giant_polygon (title: World rectangle) (Multi Surface)
```

When the layer list is read it is easy to write a working ogr2ogr command with selected layer names:

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg wfs.gpkg WFS:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs" "sf:bugsites" "sf:roads"
```

Check the result with ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo wfs.gpkg
INFO: Open of `wfs.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=This is the reference implementation of WFS 1.0.0 and WFS 1.1.0, supports all WFS operations including Transaction.
  PROVIDER_NAME=OSGeo
  TITLE=GeoServer Web Feature Service
1: sf:bugsites (title: Spearfish bug locations) (Point)
2: sf:roads (title: Spearfish roads) (Multi Curve)
```

Another question is if you want table names like `sf:bugsites` into your GeoPackage. They may be little bit tricky to use because of the colon in the name. You cannot use the `-nln` option of ogr2ogr for renaming many layers by the same. However, you can rename the tables afterwards with ogrinfo and SQL as documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html
The name of the table must be between double quotes because of the colon and the double quotes in that place of the command must be escaped with a backslash. Sorry if it feels complicated.

```
ogrinfo -sql "ALTER TABLE \"sf:roads\" RENAME TO roads" wfs.gpkg
```

The command to use for the service in your question would be

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg svo_zonen.gpkg WFS:"http://maps.zh.ch/wfs/FnsNSWFS" "ms:svo_zonen" "ms:heuschreckeninv_90_98" --debug on
```

Notice the use of `--debug on` that prints information about what GDAL is doing on the background.

Comment: Ah, with quotation marks! Great, thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: Quotation marks are not always needed but they are safe to use even if not needed. They must be used if the layer name has characters that would truncate the command too early.